# German/Special character support in form data rest web service

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jboss, jax-rs

I am currently developing small project in `Angular JS` + `Java`, where user is registering his information with his profile picture using rest webservice. Everything is working fine, except in case of special character`(Ä Ö Ü ä ö)`.

**Java :**

```
@POST
@Path("add_employee")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addEmployee(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    try {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> formDataMap = input.getFormDataMap();
        if (formDataMap != null && !formDataMap.isEmpty()) {
            InputPart inputPart = formDataMap.get("EmployeeProxy").get(0);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            //receiving wrong json below=>
            EmployeeProxy admbo = mapper.readValue(inputPart.getBodyAsString(), EmployeeProxy.class); 

            List<InputPart> profilePic = formDataMap.get("profilePic");
            .
            .
            .
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

**Angular JS :**

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('EmployeeProxy', angular.copy(JSON.stringify($scope.empInfo)));
fd.append('profilePic', $scope.myFile);

$http.post(Server.url + 'add_employee', fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).then(function (response) {
});
```

> Sending Json : {"empName": "Ä Ö Ü ä ö","empSurname": "XYZ","emailId":
>   "abc@gmail.com"}
>
> Receiving Json : {"empName": "�� �� �� �� �� ��","empSurname":
>   "XYZ","emailId": "abc@gmail.com"}

Please find below image for request header information :

[image]

This is working fine, if I am using `APPLICATION_JSON` without `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`.

Comment: Just curious: If you refer to the German characters, how about `ß`, does it work?

Comment: @Nikolas Not supporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Content-Type header is `undefined`, `RestEasy` cannot identify the charset to use and will fallback to a default (`us-ascii`).

See also:[Overwriting the default fallback content type for multipart messages](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#multipart_overwrite_default_content_type)

Edit after reading up on this: It should be the multipart body which specifies the Content-Type in order for `RestEasy` to parse the individual strings. 
[In the documentation of FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) it can be done in the following way:

**Angular JS :**

```
fd.append('EmployeeProxy', new Blob([angular.copy(JSON.stringify($scope.empInfo))], { type: "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"}));
```

**Java :**

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
EmployeeProxy admbo = mapper.readValue(json, EmployeeProxy.class);
```

Comment: Thank but still not working. Do I need to change any configuration other than adding this interceptor?

Comment: Did you try changing the Content-Type header in your client? Every input part should have a Content-Type defined. If you do this, then you don't need to write an interceptor

Comment: If I change content type with `multipart/form-data`, it gives `400` error. Also, please note, I have updated my question with request header information from my actual code.

Comment: Yes, but individual parts of your `multipart/form-data` can have a Content-Type. Hence the body can contain a Content-Type definition